# Наследование и перегрузка

Tags: c++, наследование, перегрузка-операторов

Есть базовый класс

```
class T {
private:

public:
T() {}

std::string getId() { return id; }
virtual std::string getStr() {}
virtual std::string showBin() {}
virtual T* operator+(T *b) {}
~T() {}
};
```

И 2 класса которые наследуют базовый класс

```
сlass SumbString : public T
{
public:

SumbString(std::string init) {
    initId();
    setStr(init);
}

T* operator+(T *b) override {
    return new SumbString(str + b->showBin());
}

std::string getStr() override{
    return str;
}
};
```

и

```
class BinString : public T
{
public:

BinString(std::string init) {
    initId();
    if (!checkBin(init)) {
        throw "Error. String not convert to bin";
    }
    setStr(init);
}

T* operator+(T *b) override {
    if (!checkBin(b->getStr())) {
        throw "Error. String not convert to bin";
    }
    std::string newStr = sum(str, b->getStr());
    return new BinString(newStr);
}

std::string showBin() override {
    return str;
}
};
```

Пытаюсь сделать вот так

```
T *str = new SumbString(in);
T *bin = new BinString(in);
T* strBin = str + *bin;
T* binSrt = bin + *str;
```

И у меня ругается на +  отсутствует оператор "+", соответствующий этим операнда

Comment: Ну правильно ругается, сравните тип операнда, которые вы передаете и тип операнда, который принимается у вас в методе.

Comment: @VTT ну так тип `T`

Comment: Нет, вот как раз типа T среди операндов нет.

Comment: @Данил: И что "тип `T`"? Ваши операторы требуют `T *` в качестве второго слагаемого.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы в классах определяете оператор для ссылки и указателя. А передаете указатель и ссылку... Вот он и ругается.

Стоит написать

```
T* strBin = *str + bin;
T* binSrt = *bin + str;
```

как операторы сразу находятся :)

Но правильнее такие операторы делать не членами классов, а свободными функциями.